# How do you call an Async Throws function that connects to a remote API with nested JSON properties?

Tags: json, swift, task, decodable

To preface, I am self taught and I know there are tutorials and similar questions on how to do something like this but with the small contextual differences something just isn't clicking. So any help on a solution or a tutorial more closely related to what I am trying to do would be very helpful.

I am trying to access a remote API but am struggling with the call function to execute the Async Throws function. I am trying to get the information from the JSON to be stored in a way that I can access it later for a calculation but have no idea what to put in the Task.

Minimal Reproducible Example-

Code:

```
// Struct Declarations
struct Response: Decodable {
   let data: [StockValues]
}

struct StockValues: Decodable {
   let high: Decimal
   let low: Decimal
   let close: Decimal
   let volume: Decimal
}

// Async Throws Function
class dataFetcher {
   static func Fetch() async throws -> [StockValues] {
      guard let url = URL(string: "http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod/latest")
      else {
         throw APIError.invalidServerResponse
      }
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
   let stockValues = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
   return stockValues.data
   }
}

// Call Async Throws Function
func CallFunction() {
   Task {
      let fetchedInfo = try await dataFetcher.Fetch()
      Response.data = fetchedInfo // Error: Instance member 'data' cannot be used on type 'Response'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
   }
}
```

Comment: `main` is a reserved word you shouldn't use it it would cause endless errors. From the pieces you have provided everything looks fine but no way to tell Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just make sure the `Task` part ins inside a `func`

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for the tips! I edited the question to include the Minimal Reproducible example underneath the original question if you have time or want to take a quick stab at it. I've been struggling to get this to work completely for a while and would really appreciate it. Either way, thanks for your input so far and have a nice day!

Comment: If you don’t change anything significant in your code do you truly expect a different answer?  Instead of being preoccupied making “easy to digest code” you should focus on the definition of a Minimal Reproducible example

Comment: After your first comment I tried to make a Minimal Reproducible Example and I did change the code from the original question quite a bit so I don't know what you mean there. Do you need it to be more minimal. If so what part isn't necessary, IMO someone would want to know whats going on in the Structs and Async Throws function since the Call function relies heavily on both. Stack snippets seem to be for HTML,Java,CSS so not sure if it works with Swift. You can see the exact error message I've been getting, and its the only compiler error so it's not like there are any other not relevant issues

Comment: That function is just floating, how does that tie into where you are trying to call it from? Hopefully you aren’t trying to call it without being installed in a class or struct of some kind. There are naming convention issues with your code so without knowing if you are truly trying to call that function from outside a class and referencing Response.data as a static  I can only speculate. I don’t speculate on SO. But if this is your code you can’t access Response as a static you need a variable of type Response so you can actually give it a value.

Comment: My apologies for the naming convention issues Ill try to read up on that more. I did not know it would be better to put the call function inside a class or struct. I would like my Task to be inside of a class but I don't know how to tie it together to where I am calling it from. Putting it inside another class doesn't fix the compiler error so how do I tie it in. Would I have to use a subclasse with the call function and Task inside and then override the Response properties? or is that also the wrong track. I would like to stay away from calling the function from outside a class.

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit for your UI?

Comment: I am using SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that you have a `key` for the API and that your `Response` is correct

```
//Your error refers to
//`Response` is a type it can't hold a value so `Response.data` is unacceptable
struct Response: Decodable {
    let data: [StockValues]
}

actor MarketStackService {
    //What you are attempting to do is something like this setup
    //Something global that anything can access. Using `static` to hold a response is not approriate.
    static func fetchLatest() async throws -> [StockValues] {
        //Add API key
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod/latest")
        else {
            throw APIError.invalidURL
        }
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let stockValues = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        return stockValues.data
    }
}
enum APIError: LocalizedError{
    case invalidURL
    case error(Error)
    var errorDescription: String?{
        switch self {
        case .error(let error):
            return error.localizedDescription
        default:
            let string = String(describing: self)
            return NSLocalizedString(string, comment: "AppError")
        }
    }
}
```

There are many ways of setting this is up but this is a basic `class` that works well with SwiftUI. It can hold the value from the API call and trigger changes to the `body`

```
@MainActor
class MarketStackViewModel: ObservableObject{
    //Variables are lowercased
    //A variable can hold a value. That is why you need a `class` or `struct`
    @Published var data: [StockValues] = []
    @Published var alert: (isPresented: Bool, error: APIError?)  = (false, nil)
    //`func` are lowercased
    func getLatest() async {
        do{
            let fetchedInfo = try await MarketStackService.fetchLatest()
            data = fetchedInfo
        }catch{
            alert = (true, .error(error))
        }
    }
}
```

The `View` is where the value would be displayed and where the call can be triggered.

```
//`class` and `struct` are uppercased
struct MarketStackView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: MarketStackViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if vm.data.isEmpty{
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .task {
                        //Runs the request as soon as the View displays.
                        await vm.getLatest()
                    }
            }else{
                Text(vm.data.description)
                //This is another way of making the call
                Button("Get latest") {
                    Task{
                        await vm.getLatest()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.alert(isPresented: $vm.alert.isPresented, error: vm.alert.error) {
            Button("Ok") {
                vm.alert = (false, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MarketStackView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MarketStackView()
    }
}
```

If you paste this code into a `.swift` file it should work and you can see the flow. I suggest you try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). They might help clear some concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort you've put into this issue. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately MarketStack only mentions how to input access keys with PHP, Python, etc. but not Swift and the free subscription does not allow for HTTPS encryption so just making the URL include the access key doesn't work either until I upgrade my subscription, which Ill do very soon. However I am sure the code you've provided is perfect so I'll accept the answer. I'll update you once I upgrade my subscription and like I said before thank you so much for all of your time. I hope you have a great night.

Comment: @highrock00 I would never call my code perfect but thank you. There are a lot of assumptions since I don't have a key either.

Comment: I mean I am getting some things in the log output that I am not sure what they mean like "could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x6000030ef1c0> { isDir = ?, path =" but it doesn't seem to be affecting performance. And I have only been able to get "The data could not be read because it is missing." with the Ok button but thats only because I don't have the API key figured out yet otherwise you did very good for making some assumptions.

Comment: @highrock00 a lot of people are getting that message. It seems limited to simulator so I wouldn’t worry about it.